# Plot ‘DataGridView values’ to Chart (line or point)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plot, charts, datagridview

I'm c sharp beginner. (Sorry for poor english)

Finally, I made it that load datagridview value from CSV through searching and inner-meditation.

CSV Data included 4 column(date, x, y, z). Among them i want to extract ‘date’ and ‘z’, wish to plot TimeSeries.

[image]

Time interval is 5 mins.

When i click button (Button2_Click), how can plot to Chart1 from datagridview? 
It is not matter wether lines or points.

Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: For each row in the dgv you need to add a DataPoint to the series.Points collection. Use series.AddXY(v1 v2); Make sure to pull the data as datetimes and numbers, not strings!!!

Comment: Example: `for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
{
    if (dgv["date", i].Value is null) continue;
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dgv["date", i].Value);
    double val = Convert.ToDouble(dgv["z", i].Value);
    series.Points.AddXY(date, val);
}`